# How can I perform pivot in Power BI in this given condition?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data like this in Excel. I load it into Power BI.
Here BRM_Status and Device Id should be considered the same Record and Record Id should be the same. Given input:

```
col_name       Value    Record_Id
BRM_Status                 1
Device Id       1001       2
BRM_Status      Active     3
Device Id       1002       4
```

I want to apply a pivot on Col_name and Value should be Value. And Record ID should be unique for every record.

Expected output:

```
Record Id  BRM Status  Device Id
1          null        1001
2          Active      1002
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the correlation here? The `Record_Id` don't match.
Now if your input table was meant to be:

| col_name | Value | Record_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BRM_Status |  | **1** |
| Device Id | 1001 | **1** |
| BRM_Status | Active | **2** |
| Device Id | 1002 | **2** |

Then in PowerQuery, select columns `col_name` and `Value` and then select Pivot Column, Under "Advanced options" select "Don't Aggregate".

Here's an example query:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcgryjQ8uSSwpLVbSUQIiQ6VYnWgll9SyzORUBc8UkIiBgSFcAkW5Y3JJZlkqkGGETZMRRCIWAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [col_name = _t, Value = _t, Record_Id = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"col_name", type text}, {"Value", type text}, {"Record_Id", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[col_name]), "col_name", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```